# Why does Java StringBuilder have a constructor for CharSequence and another one for String?

Tags: java, stringbuilder

Knowing that String implements CharSequence interface, so why does StringBuilder have a constructor for CharSequence and another one for String?
No indication in the javadoc !

```
public final class String
    implements java.io.Serializable, Comparable<String>, CharSequence {...}
```

```
public final class StringBuilder
    extends AbstractStringBuilder
    implements java.io.Serializable, CharSequence
{

...

    /**
     * Constructs a string builder initialized to the contents of the
     * specified string. The initial capacity of the string builder is
     * {@code 16} plus the length of the string argument.
     *
     * @param   str   the initial contents of the buffer.
     */
    public StringBuilder(String str) {
        super(str.length() + 16);
        append(str);
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a string builder that contains the same characters
     * as the specified {@code CharSequence}. The initial capacity of
     * the string builder is {@code 16} plus the length of the
     * {@code CharSequence} argument.
     *
     * @param      seq   the sequence to copy.
     */
    public StringBuilder(CharSequence seq) {
        this(seq.length() + 16);
        append(seq);
    }
...
}
```

Comment: String is only one implementatation of CharSequence. It makes sense to have another constructor that accepts any implementation of CharSequence e.g CharBuffer, Segment, String, StringBuffer or StringBuilder.

Comment: If you check subsequent calls, you'll see that there are different implementations of `java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append` for `String` and `CharSequence`. Seems the string version is optimized specifically.

Comment: @ernest_k But the append(CharSequence s) is calling append(String str) if the charSequence is instanceof String !!

Comment: @sechanakira Liskov will not be happy.

Comment: @AbdelRahmane Exactly. So they prefer the `append(String)` to `append(CharSequence)` implementation. And if you look at the actual code, you can guess with me that `append(String)` is optimal.

Comment: @AbdelRahmane LSP is not violated: if you passed a string to the charsequence overload, you would get the same *result*. Moreover, LSP doesn't apply to overloads: overloads are unrelated methods which *happen* to have the same name.

Comment: It's just a little performance detail. Which is important, since this class is heavily used everywhere. It's a core class and as such every detail matters. Note that, even if you do not actively use the class, Java uses it internally to replace and optimize `String` usages in your code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Optimization. If I am not mistaken, there are two implementations of append. `append(String)` is more efficient than `append(CharSequence)` where `CharSequence` is a string. If I had to do some extra routine to check to make sure the `CharSequence` is compatible with String, convert it to String, and run the append(String), that would be longer than append(String) directly. Same result. Different speed.

Comment: "StringBuilder is generally meant for strings, hence the name" `StringBuilder` is meant to *build* `String`s. Its name says nothing about what it expects them to be built *from*.

Comment: @AndyTurner indeed, similar to how if you have some `CarBuilder` it doesn't necessarily have to *accept* cars. It needs car *parts*. If it does accept Car objects, it would likely be to re-use their parts.

Comment: The specific optimization here is that String provides a `getChars` method that utilizes the `System.arraycopy` to copy the chars from the String's internal char array directly to the StringBuilders's char array in one shot.  The naive `CharSequence` version has to loop over the sequence calling `charAt` for every index.

Comment: @JimmyJames Yeh wasn't sure the exact implementation... just knew there was an extra routine that would be unnecessary for Strings.